# Textbox label not updating on page change

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am creating a report using SSRS which contains pages separated by individual account holders.  Each page represents one account and I am using a textbox label in the header to display the name of the account; however, I am having trouble getting the textbox label to show different name as I navigate through pages.

So for example, on page 1 the account label in the header would show `Account A`, and on page 2 it should show `Account B`.  However, right now it always shows `Account A` regardless of the page it is on.  The expression of the label looks like this :  `=(Fields!Account_Name.Value)`

Do I need to create a grouping or some sort in order to have the account change depending on the grouping of account name?  If so how do I go about doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to display the group field in the page header.
The expression would be something like this:

```
=ReportItems!Account_Name.Value
```

Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1bc58a64-db73-4eda-9f86-21d6f9e23c84/ssrs-to-display-page-header-as-per-the-group?forum=sqlreportingservices